# Superblock checksum does not match superblock while trying to open /dev/sda2

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, fsck

I attempted to fix it with fsck and e2fsck -b  but it didn't work. Actually, my screen goes full of numbers every time I try to fix this issue with those commands. Looks like it all started when I tried to reboot Ubuntu (unclean reboot), when fixing another similar problem. I'm pretty new to Linux so I have no clue what to do. Thanks in advance.